# Installing and running Apache on Amazon EC2 Micro Instance

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

So I just got an Amazon EC2 Micro instance. I installed Apache using `yum install httpd`. But now, how can I get Apache to run? If I run `ps -A` it doesn't say that its running, nor when I go to `ec2.chigs.me`. How can I start it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the distribution you've installed. Since you used yum I guess it's CentOS/RedHat/Fedora or similar. Try `service httpd start` or something like that. `chkconfig httpd on` should have it started automatically after reboots.